# Google street-view JS calculate heading to face marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

How do i get google truck location and heading to calculate street view heading properly in this example somehow i cannot do `panorama.getLocation()` it saying unknown however showing in firebug when i do `console.log(panorama)` and see object methods.

```
function initialize() {
    var myPlace = {lat: 33.976827,lng: -118.163889};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: myPlace,
        zoom: 18
    });

    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('pano'), {
            position: myPlace          
        });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPlace,
        map: map
    });

    marker_pano = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPlace,
        map: panorama
    });

    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panorama.getPosition(), marker.getPosition());

    panorama.setPov({
        heading: heading,
        pitch: 0
    });

    map.setStreetView(panorama);

}        

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z3b4ubb3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @geocodezip solution, here is another way to achieve what you want:

```
var panorama, myPlace;

function initialize() {

    myPlace = {
        lat: 33.976827,
        lng: -118.163889
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: myPlace,
        zoom: 18
    });

    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: myPlace
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPlace,
        map: map
    });

    map.setStreetView(panorama);

    var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    sv.getPanorama({
        location: myPlace,
        radius: 50
    }, processSVData);
}

function processSVData(data, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {

        var marker_pano = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myPlace,
            map: panorama
        });

        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(data.location.latLng, marker_pano.getPosition());

        panorama.setPov({
            heading: heading,
            pitch: 0
        });
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ru3m707f/)</kbd>

Comment: You forgot timeout so marker shows on top left corner but i know how to fix that, however your overall answer is closer to my final approach i am using so easier for me to understand. Therefor i mark your answer correct even though 
geocodezip solution works too.

Comment: What browser are you using? For me it works with the above code, without timeout. I am on Chrome / Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The panorama is asynchronous.  To get its position, wait for the `position_changed` event to fire:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function () {
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(panorama.getPosition(), marker.getPosition());
    panorama.setPov({
        heading: heading,
        pitch: 0
    });
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z3b4ubb3/2/)

Comment: I was just trying with the StreetViewService (which also works) but that's way easier! Nice catch ;)

Comment: And I may add for @Roman Toasov that the reason why his script would not work is, as you mentioned, the asynchronous aspect and that therefore `panorama.getPosition()` and `marker.getPosition()` would return the exact same values, so the heading would always be `0`.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, you will see the use of `setTimeout`, not sure why that is necessary or if there is an event that can be used to replace it, but without it the marker wasn't anchored correctly on the `panorama` (it would appear in the upper left hand corner until I moved the streetview with the mouse)

Comment: Note: if you do this on position_changed without removing it again then any time the user moves around they will be aligned to look back at that point again.  Possibly not a desirable outcome.